# Smooth of metric under Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Let $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold.$g$ evolve under $\partial_tg_{ij}(x,t)=-2R_{ij}(x,t)$.

When I read Shi's derivative estimate, I need the metric $g_{ij}(x,t)$ to be continuous with respect to the parameter $t$, and $\forall t\in (0,T], x\in M$, $g_{ij}(x,t)$ to be smooth in $x$. But I don't know how to show that.

Forgive me so ignorant, I just a beginner of geometry.

Thanks very much for detail answer or hint.

Comment: @John Ma   Do you have any idea ?